# Vue + nested components created

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Is there a way to create nested components in vue.js?

```
<newform>
    <field></field>
    <field></field>
    <field></field>
    <field></field>
    <submit></submit>
</newform>
```

In my case, only the newform component is rendered, but not the nested components.

### My Code:

**app.js**

```
Vue.http.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = document.querySelector('#token').getAttribute('value');
Vue.config.debug = true;
Vue.config.async = true;
 
/**
 * The base Vue Instance
 */
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: {
        'new-form': require('./components/form')
    }
});
```

**form.js**

```
module.exports = {
    template: "Hallo Welt",     
    props: ['url', 'method'],    
    components: {
        'field': require('./field')
    },    
    created: function() {
        console.log("Form Component created");
    }
}
```

**field.js**

```
module.exports = {    
    template: 'Ein Text feld',    
    props: ['name', 'type'],   
    create: function() {
        console.log("Field Component created");
    }
}
```

[Link to code sample](http://laravel.io/bin/8Kww7)

Comment: Can you add the actual DOM that does get rendered? Also, the "create" function on field.js should be "created".

Answer (score 4):

The functionality you are describing is called a [slot](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Content-Distribution-with-Slots) in Vue. It allows you to nest content inside a component you're including by using a special `<slot>` tag in its template. [Here's an example](https://jsfiddle.net/yMv7y/2167/).

Looking at that link, it's important to note the components aren't in the parent-child relationship you're trying to imply. Your `form` doesn't need to specify `field` under its components. It has a slot and it doesn't care what will show up in it.

Both `form` and `field` should be specified under components in your `app.js`, that's where all the heavy lifting is done and that's where both components are included.

Answer (score 0):

You can use components, like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/hajkrupo/5/

```
<body>
    <encapsulated-component inline-template>
        <header>
            <cart-status></cart-status>
        </header>
        <cart></cart>
        <item some-prop="1"></item>
        <item some-prop="2"></item>
        <item some-prop="3"></item>
    </encapsulated-component>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to render `<field>` in `<newform>`, so you need to show the `field` template in `newform` template. Like this

**form.js**

```
module.exports = {    
  template: 'Ein Text feld<slot></slot>',    
  props: ['name', 'type'],   
  create: function() {
    console.log("Field Component created");
  }
}
```

Another point is to require `field.js` in `app.js` not `form.js`.

Here is the example http://www.webpackbin.com/4k9vxYrCl.

Hopes to help you.